# A lemma on function spaces

Tags: general-topology, functions, metric-spaces

This is a lemma about function spaces. I'm not really understanding it however. Can someone try explaining it to me?

Lemma: let $X$ be in |SET| $(Y, d)$ in |MET|, $f_n$, $f$ is in $Y^X$. Then $f_n\to f$ if and only if $f_n \to f$ uniformly.

Comment: I assume $X$ should also be a metric space.

Comment: An important part is missing: $Y^X$ is also a metric space, with a metric defined by .... If you bring this part into picture, the solution is not far away.

Comment: I think you would start with saying for all epsilon greater than 0, there's an N for all n>=N where the distance is less than epsilon